# Get filename from a gulp watch into a gulp task

Tags: css, sass, gulp

I use gulp.

**Gulp watch**

```
gulp.task('default',function() {
    gulp.watch([
        'assets/scss/**/*.scss',
    ], ['css']);
});
```

**Gulp CSS task**

This task is using `style.scss` which includes other scss files. When it's saved it's named `style.css`

```
gulp.task('css', function() {
    gulp.src(['assets/scss/style.scss'])
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('site/plugins/theme/assets/css'))
    ;
});
```

In my case I want it to be like this:

```
gulp.task('css', function() {
    gulp.src(['assets/scss/' + filename])
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('site/plugins/theme/assets/css'))
    ;
});
```

And in the watch like this:

```
gulp.task('default',function() {
    gulp.watch([
        'assets/scss/**/*.scss',
    ], ['css', 'my-filename']);
});
```

Send a filename from gulp watch to be used in gulp src. Is it possible? How?

Comment: No, it's not possible. You cannot pass parameters to a gulp task. You have to refactor the code and put it into its own function.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this with calling a separate task, but you can do it with an anonymous function in the watcher

```
gulp.task('default', function() {
 gulp.watch(['assets/scss/**/*.scss'], function (obj) {

  return gulp.src(obj.path, {"base": "assets/scss/"})
   .pipe(sass())
   .pipe(gulp.dest('site/plugins/theme/assets/css'));

 });
});
```